# Adding elements to a SVG in Polymer element

Tags: svg, polymer

Below you see a small test element. It creates a SVG and whenever you click the SVG it should add a circle. Inspecting the element shows that the circles are indeed added (I know the position isn't exactly correct), but they are not shown.

This is `svg-test.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module name="svg-test">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="svg-test.css">
  <template>
    <svg id="test" width$="{{width}}" height$="{{height}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'svg-test',

      properties: {
      width: {
        type: String,
        value: "200"
      },
      height: {
        type: String,
        value: "200"
      }
    },

    listeners: {
      'test.tap': 'addCircle'
    },

    addCircle: function(e) {
      var uri = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
      var svg = this.$$('svg');
      var circle = document.createElementNS(uri,'circle');
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'r', '5');
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'cx', e.detail.x);
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'cy', e.detail.y);
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'fill', 'white');
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'stroke', 'black');
      circle.setAttributeNS(uri, 'stroke-width', '2');
      svg.appendChild(circle);
    }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is a test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>svg-test Demo</title>

  <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="svg-test.html">
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <p>An example of svg-test looks like this:</p>

  <svg-test></svg-test>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "svg-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: As I said in the introduction: the circles are added to the SVG, but they are not visible. I would expect them to be visible. I checked this in the most recent versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although SVG elements are in the SVG namespace, attributes are typically in the null namespace so you want this...

```
  var circle = document.createElementNS(uri,'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('r', '5');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', e.detail.x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', e.detail.y);
  circle.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
  circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
  circle.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solves the problem. Do you maybe have an idea how I can get the correct position for the circles? I need to get the offset of the SVG element. In an earlier version I used `svg.offsetLeft` and `svg.offsetTop`, but these no longer seem to work (they are undefined).

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)